# .NET Core Web API causing 307 Redirect issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a .NET Core Web API using the following command:

> dotnet new webapi -n MyOrderService

I have .netcore 3.1 installed on my Windows 10 Pro.

When I try and invoke my service locally in Postman I keep getting "**307 Temporary Redirect**".
The endpoint I used was http://localhost:5000/Order/Get

I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. Can someone assist me please?

The OrderController at the moment only contains only a single method to test the API:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<OrderController> _logger;

    public OrderController(ILogger<OrderController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
       return "Up";
    }

}
```

Here is my ConfigureServices() method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

Here is my Configure() method:

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
       
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });


    }
```

**launchSettings.json file**

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
 "windowsAuthentication": false,
 "anonymousAuthentication": true,
 "iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:34483",
  "sslPort": 44311
  }
},
 "profiles": {
   "IIS Express": {
     "commandName": "IISExpress",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "environmentVariables": {
     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "Dapr.OrderService": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   }
 }
}
}
```

When I start the service I see the below output:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Content root path: C:\dev\netcore\MyOrderService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and codes, I found you used the wrong url to access the web api action method.

You should use `http://localhost:5000/Order/` instead of the `http://localhost:5000/Order/Get` to access the get method.

Besides, if you don't want to use https, you could comment out the  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, then it will work well.

I also created a test demo on my side, it works well.

[image]

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for this, it worked. It's been a while since I've worked with .NET Core.